# How to know disk quota on network share in windows?

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, windows-server-2003, quota

I connect to a share on a windows server and I have a quota of unknown size. All the tools I have seen are reporting the disk size/disk free space, not the quota size for myself.

The only way I can figure out my quotas is to keep writing junk until I reach the quota. There must be a better way than this?

My PC is windows XP and the servers are mainly 2003server.

Answer (score 2):

If you map the share as a network drive it will show you the limit and the amount used.

[image: windows server]

Comment: Thats not WinXP. In winxp it just shows the size of the disks on the server, not of your quota space.

Comment: I realize the screenshot isn't. Except here my xp machine shows the quota.

Comment: Mr static > Are you connecting to a 2008 Server?  2003 server does quota by the whole drive (ie on the whole of the D: for example, no matter how many folders/shares you have access to), rather than by folder.